# PHPUnit enable Color Output

Tags: command-line, phpunit

I am running PHPUnit from command line on Windows 7. I tried to enable color output via `phpunit --color`. But it still display same, no color output. How can I get color output of PHPUnit from command line on Win7?

Comment: Is your problem that the option is actually `--colors` with an s?

Comment: @Schleis Hi, I just tried with `phpunit --colors`. But still the same, I see no color. How can I get color displayed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to use http://softkube.com/blog/ansi-command-line-colors-under-windows or get some sane console like conemu https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/

Also, I suggest to download git for windows and use bash as your default shell.

Comment: it did for me, when google the error I found it was because of installing this, removing it then solved the problem. Maybe there's a way to get them running side by side, but for me it caused a conflict.

Answer (score 2):

Download Git for Windows, run phpunit from the command line in the Bash shell, and you will get colors.

Comment: If you are talking bash console mingw64 it is not very useful on Win, as it seems to be slash-sensitive. Only forward slashes are allowed. Backward slashes are removed.