# Php artisan dusk does not show the result in red or green colour

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-dusk

Using Laravel 5.4 and installed Dusk(1.7) and phpunit(5.7)

The result has no color indications, like normally its Red or Green Color

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using git bash or other terminals/command prompts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPUnit enable Color Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825529/phpunit-enable-color-output)